# convert date to unix timestamp in powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime, timestamp

I want to convert any date time (not current) format into unix timestamp.
$dateToConvert = "2018-12-11 01:00:00"

input: $dateToConvert
output: 1544490000 (value that i got from converter)

will be really thankful for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to convert the `$dateToConvert` to a `[DateTime]` object before messing with it in PowerShell. You can then change the format of it to seconds by using the `-UFormat` parameter.

```
[datetime]$dateToConvert  = "2018-12-11 01:00:00"
Get-Date -Date $dateToConvert  -UFormat %s
```

More information regarding changing the format of the `Get-Date` can be found on the [MSDocs Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6)

EDIT:

As per comment, you can just do the below for the same result.

```
Get-Date -Date "2018-12-11 01:00:00" -UFormat %s
```

Comment: +1 for the `-UFormat` hint, but note that you can pass the date/time string directly to `Get-Date`, which implicitly converts it to `[datetime]` (using the rules of the invariant culture, as with the cast).